# Where to find all the third party packages or modules installed in a Flask project

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to flask ,but in Django I can find all the installed third party packages in
settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS=[
'third_party_app,'
]
```

Is there any module or any way in flask ,I can easily find all the installed third party packages ?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect `sorted(sys.modules.keys())` to see what has been `import`ed so far.

Or ask `$ pip freeze` about packages that *could* be imported.